# Как использовать модуль ffi с библиотекой moonsharp?

Tags: c#, lua, ffi

Столкнулся с проблемой в moonsharp, которая не позволяет подключить модуль ffi, как это можно исправить?
[image: ffi not found]

Comment: Муншарп - это интерпретатор Lua, написанный на C#?  Никак не исправить, наверное.  Возможно ли на C# в рантайме подключать на лету произвольные DDL-ки и вызывать из них произвольные функции, не известные на момент компиляции?  Если это невозможно, то FFI на C# не реализуема в принципе.  Если это возможно, то вам придётся написать FFI-модуль для муншарпа самому (или написать муншарп-обёртку для чужого модуля FFI, если в природе есть FFI для C#).

Comment: А для чего вам ffi?  Возможно, на C# вашу задачу можно решить без FFI, благо библиотек у C# много.